# Flutter: How to hide downloaded audio/video files from rooted devices?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I want user's to download audio from remote and access the file within the app. I don't want any other source to provide them the access. If I store the file in application directory, it works fine in normal devices. But rooted android devices can access the files. How can I hide these?

I tried dividing the files into chunks. but these can be merged and can be used as a normal file.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to `file.setPermissions(FilePermission(0o600));` to restrict file permissions or use `pointycastle: ^3.7.3` the library for encryption and decryption.